# Turning an array element into a link, which acts like a "POST" method in a form.

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, multidimensional-array, synonym

I have a webpage which contains a form, like the following:

```
<Form action=”search.php” method=”POST”>
<fieldset>
<legend> Enter your search below </legend>
<textarea name=”query”> </textarea>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The users text is read from `query` and search results are displayed using code in the following section:

```
if ($_POST['query'])
{
//Users query is read and results from a search API are displayed
}
```

The next thing that happens is that a list of synonyms are generated,  stored in a multidimensional array called `$synonyms` which I have displayed in a left-hand-navigation bar, using the code shown below. `$newline` prints a newline (as the variable name suggests)

Example of a `$synonyms` array:

```
array(3) 
{ [0]=> array(2) 
    { [0]=> string(9) "chelonian" 
      [1]=> string(17) "chelonian reptile" } 

 [1]=> array(6) 
{ [0]=> string(7) "capsize" 
  [1]=> string(11) "turn turtle" 
  [2]=> string(8) "overturn" 
  [3]=> string(9) "turn over" 
  [4]=> string(8) "tip over" 
  [5]=> string(9) "tump over" } 

 [2]=> array(4) 
 { [0]=> string(4) "hunt" 
   [1]=> string(3) "run" 
   [2]=> string(9) "hunt down" 
   [3]=> string(10) "track down" } 

}
```

Code used to output the array:

```
foreach ($synonyms as $test)
{   foreach ($test as $test2)
    {
    echo $test2.$newline.$newline;
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is:

Turn each synonym into a clickable link..if the user clicks the synonym "capsize", the word capsize is sent to the section where the synonym(previously `query`) is read and processed into results.. ie. back to this section:

```
if ($_POST['query'])
{
// Synonym is read and results from a search API are displayed
// Previously 'query' was read here
// The cycle continues again
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions on this one would be great, thanks guys.

Comment: Clickable links will always try to do a GET request. if you need that to be a POSt, then you'll have to use `<form>`s, or use javascript to intercept the click and build a POST dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use GET in search form. Then list synonyms as shown below

```
foreach ($synonyms as $test)
{   foreach ($test as $test2)
    {
     // I used <br/> for newline
     printf('<a href="search.php?query=%1$s">%1$s</a><br/>', $test2);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** And obviously, you should replace $_POST['query'] with $_GET['query']

Comment: Hey oozel. Thanks. It does indeed turn term into links. When I click it, it goes to mywebsite.com/search.php?query=capsize.. however, this just displays the form on my page. I may need to do some more tweeking. Thank you, and I will attempt to implement your solution very soon!.. What does `%1$s` signify in your code?

Comment: It's the placeholder for string value. In other words, it indicates that a string value will come here (and your string value is $test2). You should take a look at **sprintf** manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php